# Type Incompatibility With Vendor Folder

Tags: go, jenkins, dependency-management, vendor

I am deploying a Go application via Jenkins and running some tests.

All my tests pass locally even if I remove all third-party libraries from my GOPATH because I have populated my `vendor` folder via `godep save`.

However, when Jenkins runs my tests, it reports type incompatibilities between the GitHub version and vendor version:

```
mypackage/MyFile_test.go:65:22: cannot use MY_VARIABLE
(type "github.com/gocql/gocql".UUID) as type 
"myproject/vendor/github.com/gocql/gocql".UUID in assignment
```

I have tried using `Dep` (the Go team's official vendor manager) instead of `godep` but it did not resolve the issue.

Do I need to tell my tests to use "myproject/vendor/github.com/gocql/gocql" instead of "github.com/gocql/gocql"? (***UPDATE:*** Apparently this is illegal and will give the error `must be imported as github.com/gocql/gocql`.)

How do I solve this?

***UPDATES:***

- I'm using Go 1.12.1 both on my local machine and Jenkins server.
- I am not using `go modules` of any kind.

Here is the Go section of my Jenkins Pipeline code. Could it have something to with this issue?

```
steps {                                           
    // Create our project directory.
    sh 'cd ${GOPATH}/src'
    sh 'mkdir -p ${GOPATH}/src/myproject'

    // Copy all files in our Jenkins workspace to our project directory.                
    sh 'cp -r ${WORKSPACE}/* ${GOPATH}/src/myproject'

    // Copy all files in our "vendor" folder to our "src" folder.
    sh 'cp -r ${WORKSPACE}/vendor/* ${GOPATH}/src'

    // Build the app.
    sh 'go build'               

    // Remove cached test results.
    sh 'go clean -cache'

    // Run Unit Tests.
    sh 'go test ./... -v -short'    
}
```

Comment: what version of go are you using? Are the versions the same in Jenkins and your local dev?

Comment: @Varcorb I'm using Go 1.12.1 on both my local and Jenkins server, but I assume that shouldn't have anything to do with this issue because it looks more like Go treating the `vendor` library as a different one from the non-`vendor` library. Shouldn't Go be smart enough to know they are identical given that `/vendor/` is the only difference in their name?

Comment: @Varcorb I assume this because Jenkins will only look at the `vendor` folder if it can't find the third-party library in the GOPATH. That means it should treat the `vendor` and non-`vendor` libraries the same, shouldn't it?

Comment: The reason I asked is because 1.12.1 has `go modules` feature and might not be looking for a `GOPATH`? Is the `GO111MODULE` env var set to `on`?.

Comment: @Varcorb I am not using `go modules` because I do not think it is that widely-used yet. Some third-party libraries that I use are not fully compatible with it, which should be fine because I have not configured Go in Jenkins to use `go modules`.

Comment: I had a lot of issues at first when I switched to `1.12` with `modules`. But since modules will be `on` by default in `1.13` and `GOPATH` will be depreciated I decided to start using it. Now I love modules instead of using a `GOPATH`

Comment: @Varcorb Hmm... So `go modules` might somehow solve vendor issues like this? How so?

Comment: try to update your vendor dependencies to date?

Comment: have you tried setting the `GO111MODULE` env var to `off`?

Comment: @kkesley I assume that since there is no `GO111MODULE` env var set up in Jenkins, it shouldn't have any effect, correct?

Comment: @HolaYang All my vendor dependencies are actually up to date. I assume Jenkins is getting confused with the `vendor` and non-`vendor` libraries due to directory issues.

Comment: ***UPDATE:*** I have added my Go Jenkins pipeline code above. Could it have something to do with the issue?

Comment: @kkesley I thought that would only be for 1.13 onwards. Even on my local machine there is no `GO111MODULE` env var and all my tests pass.

Comment: @FloatingSunfish you're right! I must've mistaken it! sorry!

Comment: why need to cp vender?? `sh 'cp -r ${WORKSPACE}/vendor/* ${GOPATH}/src'`

Comment: @zzn Yeah, I'm looking into that myself. This is a pretty old project that I'm rewriting. It looks like the original motive was that Jenkins was looking for Go codes in GOPATH as well as where the code was pulled from Git. Here's the error when the Go files are moved to GOPATH (where they belong) and there are no more files where they were pulled: `can't load package: package .: no Go files in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproject-pipeline@2`

Comment: I figured it out and posted the answer below. Many thanks to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suspected, the issue was with my Jenkins configuration (because everything worked fine locally).

Turns out each `sh` line represented a new shell terminal, so all I needed to do was put everything into just one `sh` section like so:

```
steps {
    // Create our expected project directory inside our GOPATH's src folder.
    // Move our project codes (and its vendor folder) to that folder.
    // Build and run tests.
    sh '''                    
        mkdir -p ${GOPATH}/src/myproject
        mv ${WORKSPACE}/* ${GOPATH}/src/myproject
        cd ${GOPATH}/src/myproject
        go build
        go clean -cache
        go test ./... -v -short
       '''
}
```

Many thanks to everyone who helped!